# rsync - delete files from source dir even nothing is copied to destination because of option "ignore-existing"

Tags: rsync

I have a folder on the flash drive connected to my router where i copy files that should synced to my HTPC when its starting. At start there ths little sync script is running

```
rsync --remove-source-files --ignore-existing -a source/ destination
```

This moves files to the HTPC and deletes the files on the source dir. But when the file already exists nothing is copied (there is no check for timestamps, only a file name check). But i want to delete the files in the source dir when rsync recognizes that there is already a file with the same name in the destination dir.

Can this be done with rsync?

Comment: You mean you want `source/` to be empty after the `rsync` operation, no matter what? Why not just remove it and recreate it with `rm -rf source; mkdir source` after the `rsync` command in that case?

Comment: @Kusalananda That strategy would not guarantee that the files actually exist in the destination.

Answer (score 0):

Good question. I have a similar use case, where I used filezilla to perform my upload (as it would - in this particular case - be faster due to parallel connections) and wanted rsync to merely do verification and delete transferred source files.

I forced rsync to do that with `-c`. Only then, it would also delete the source files where it wouldn't do so before, with the normal skip check (based on size+time).